# Explain my AppStats graph for a db.get

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I did a `db.get([356 keys])` and it took 8 seconds. Here is an excerpt of the AppStats graph for this operation:
http://vvcap.net/db/iXvU5LtfG6tp04-kjqvp.htp

Is 8 seconds normal for 356 keys? And why is the CPU time be bigger than the API CPU time? If anything I would expect the API CPU time to be bigger, since entities are fetched in parallel.

All 356 keys are for this model:

```
class Molecule(db.Model):
    meaning = db.StringProperty()
    short_desc = db.StringProperty()
    official = db.BooleanProperty(default=False)
    phrasing = db.ReferenceProperty()
    atoms = db.ListProperty(db.Key) # ~3 list elements on average
    keywords = db.ListProperty(db.Key) # ~20 list elements on average
    phrasings = db.ListProperty(db.Key) # ~1 list element on average
    add_dt = db.DateTimeProperty()
    modify_dt = db.DateTimeProperty()
    delete_dt = db.DateTimeProperty()
    _ucase_meaning = db.StringProperty()
```

Comment: was the query keys only or were you getting the full entities?

Comment: If he is using `db.get()` then full entities are being retrieved.

Comment: @Liron: could you post the definition of the model(s) being retrieved?  Are you running in the local or production environment?

Comment: @David Added the model definition. I'm running on the production environment.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Is the query time pretty consistently around 8 seconds?  Based on that model, each entity's maximum storage size is about 2233 bytes; so 356 entities would take up to 6.4Mb.  This might contribute to the query time if your entities are indeed this big; this would be pretty close to the [1MB maximum](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/overview.html#Quotas_and_Limits) that `db.get()` can return.

Comment: Yeah, it's consistently at least 6 seconds. Is it against the spirit of App Engine to Get a few hundred keys while serving a request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

6-8 seconds is certainly high, but the models you're fetching are fairly complex. The reason for the long time is due to the number and size of the entities you're fetching - most of the CPU time not accounted for by API time is the time spent waiting for the request to complete (eg, blocked on IO from one or more of the tabletservers).

There are several approaches you can take to speed things up:

1. Fetch fewer entities.
2. Split your model into two parts, the 'full' model and the 'summary'. Only fetch the summary entities whenever possible.
3. Memcache the result of the fetch.
4. Memcache the output that you generate with the fetched data.